# How to refactor ES6 class which uses "this" as a parameter in super?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, openlayers

[ol-geocoder](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-geocoder) is a an extension to the [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org) library. Since the latest major update to v7, OpenLayers ships with ES6 classes. So the extensions which were transpiling classes to ES5 are now incompatible with OpenLayers v7.

[ol-layerswitcher](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher/commit/85f7957abb5e353a27674d65361f4b399c7ab7dd) solved this issue by removing babel transpiling. I am trying the same with [ol-geocoder](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-geocoder/issues/258) but the [Base class constructor](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-geocoder/blob/master/src/base.js) is written in such a way that it accesses `this` before calling `super` and even uses `this` while calling `super` which throws an error since `this` cannot be accessed before calling `super`.

How should I refactor this code to call `super` before using `this`?

Comment: *is written in such a way that it accesses this before calling super and even uses this while calling super which throws an error since this cannot be accessed before calling super* What did ever make this work?? And who writes such bad incompatible code?

Comment: Don't know who wrote it. I'm trying to fix it now.

Comment: Try moving the super to the top of the constructor `super({ element: type === CONTROL_TYPE.NOMINATIM ? $html.els.container : undefined });`

Comment: The $html comes from HTML class which was taking "this" as a parameter. What I did to solve this is change the HTML class to take the "options" parameter of the class instead of passing the whole class since only the "options" parameter is being used in HTML class. After that, moved all code instances of "this" below the super call.